# RegEx negation to handle decimal values in Pandas dataframe using .replace()

Tags: python, regex, pandas, regex-negation

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
foo = {
    'Sales' : [200, 'bar', 400, 500],
    'Expenses' : [70, 90, 'baz', 170],
    'Other' : [2.5, 'spam', 70, 101.25]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(foo)

Sales   Expenses    Other
200     70          2.5
bar     90          spam
400     baz         70
500     170         101.25
```

I'd like to remove non-numeric values and replace with `NaN`.  I do so as follows:

```
df['Other'] = df['Other'].replace('[^0-9\.]', np.NaN, regex=True)
```

This gets me:

```
Sales   Expenses    Other
200     70          2.5
bar     90          NaN
400     baz         70
500     170         101.25
```

The decimals are not handled.  I would expect `[^0-9\.]` to handle the decimal, but it doesn't.  The following (without the escaped decimal) results in the same output:

```
df['Other'] = df['Other'].replace('[^0-9]', np.NaN, regex=True)

Sales   Expenses    Other
200     70          2.5
bar     90          NaN
400     baz         70
500     170         101.25
```

How do I treat the decimals?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'non-numeric'. Are you looking for whole (integer) numbers? The decimal numbers have the type of float, so I don't think regex can be used unless you convert all values to strings.

Comment: I believe int types can be handled with `[^0-9]`.  The issue is that I don't know how to treat ints **and** floats in the same column.

Comment: what do you mean by "treat"? Do you want to replace decimals with NaN too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex will only work on strings.
You can cast all values to strings using .astype(str)

```
df['Other'].astype(str).replace('[^0-9]', np.NaN, regex=True)
```